# "Proper" way to exit from a C/C++ program on erroneous input/behavior

Tags: c++, c, exit

Quick question.. is there a "proper" way to terminate from a C/C++ program on invalid input? Thus far, my career in C/C++ has involved doing something like this:

```
// C
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Usage: %s [some param] [some param]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* rest of program */

    return 0;
}
```

In C++, it could be `cerr` instead of `fprintf(srderr...)` and `iostream` instead or `stdio.h`.

Is this an OK/acceptable way, or is there a standard I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: The `<stdlib.h>` header defines the `EXIT_FAILURE` macro as a value you can return from main or pass to `exit()` to indicate failure.

Comment: why not std::cerr to report messages.

Comment: @Loki because that's not valid C and the question applies to both C and C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basic convention is to return a *non-zero* value to indicate some error condition on exit. A return value of *zero* is used to indicate normal program termination.

There's nothing to prevent you from coming up with list of non-zero values and associating them with specific error conditions so that one could identify the specific error based on an exit value.

For instance if a shell program was running your program it could then take appropriate action  by examining the exit value. Error messages to *stderr* are useful for us, but exit values can be used programatically and provide additional flexibility.

Usually values 0 - 127 are resevered for your use, the rest for the system according to [Job crashes and exit codes](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/Computing/Environment/Tools/Batch/exitcode.html)

Comment: So the non-zero value I return on error is arbitrary, I can decide that `return 1` means X, and `return 2` means Y?

Comment: @yes, you can associate any value with an error condition, it's your program. Usually values 0 - 127 are resevered for your use, see this: http://www.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/Computing/Environment/Tools/Batch/exitcode.html

Comment: On BSD, and sometimes on Linux, there is even a standard set of error numbers in `sysexits.h`. Here's the man page: http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/3/sysexits/ .

Comment: Most shells were interpret a non zero code as a failure. This will then affect how they execute other commands.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of DOS .bat files it's the convention that programs that execute successfully return 0, this is then checked by the `%ERRORLEVEL%` value in the batch file. Non-zero values indicate something went wrong, the exact value returned is really up to the programmer and should be documented somewhere. [More here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490954.aspx)

Unix is very similar but seems to have a bit more specfication according to [this](http://ry.ca/blog/tag/errorlevel/)

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can call `exit()` function, instead of `return`. That is within main, `retrun exp` is equivalent to `exit(exp)`. The argument of exit is available to whatever process called this, so the success or failure of the program can be tested by another program that uses this as a sub-process. Conventionally, a return value 0 signals that all is well; non-zero values usually signal abnormal situations.

`exit` has the advantage that it can be called from other functions.